I am using mammoth it is working fine but it not give styling of word document while converting?
I want basically docx to html with the styling of docx also while conversion mammoth gives me HTML but not styling I want to convert word to HTML having inline styles of word docx
const handleFileUpload = (event) => {

const file = event.target.files?.[0];
if (file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    const arrayBuffer = event.target?.result;
    if (arrayBuffer) {
      mammoth.convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer })
        .then((result) => {
          const html = result.value;
          console.log(html)
          setContent(html);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error("Error converting .docx to HTML", err));
    }
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

};

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
